# Java difference between "split(regEx)" and "split(regEx, 0)"?

Tags: java, split

Is there any difference between using `split(regEx)` and `split(regEx, 0)`?

Because the output is for the cases I tested the same. Ex:

```
String myS = this is stack overflow;
String[] mySA = myS.split(' ');
```

results in `mySA === {'this','is','stack,'overflow'}`

And

```
String myS = this is stack overflow;
String[] mySA = myS.split(' ', 0);
```

also results in `mySA === {'this','is','stack,'overflow'}`

Is there something "hidden" going on here? Or something else which needs to be known about the `.split(regEx, 0)`?

Comment: They are the same. It's in the documentation.

Comment: What I seriously do not understand: it is in the Javadoc. It is directly in the source code. Why do you need to spent 5 minutes to write up a question for that? (sure, the question itself is nicely formatted and clear; no doubt about that)

Comment: I am working with Apex(which is by my information "inspired" by Java) and I googled "split java", my question how I posted it here and didn't find the official Docs(oracle). In other docs(and in the apex docs) you don't find that they are the same.

Comment: You can find the official Java API documentation here: [Java SE 8 API Specifcation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are essentially the same.

Quoted from [`String.split(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) documentation:

> **This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero.** Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

Comment: Thank you :)! Is oracle.com the "official" Java documentation?

Comment: @FrederikWitte yes. Oracle effectively owns Java.

Comment: @FrederikWitte: For this behavior, since it is documented, different implementations should exhibit the same behavior. In general, different implementation of Java Class Library may have some differences due to undocumented behavior/bug in the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question. Yes they're same.

Please find the split method of String class which intern calls the `split(regex,0)` method.

```
public String[] split(String regex) {
    return split(regex, 0);
}
```

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is
>   applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If
>   the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at
>   most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and
>   the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched
>   delimiter. If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as
>   many times as possible and the array can have any length. **If n is zero
>   then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible**, the array
>   can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded

For  example the following code can give you some insight.

```
String myS = "this is stack overflow";
String[] mySA = myS.split(" ", 2);
String[] withOutLimit = myS.split(" "); 
System.out.println(mySA.length); // prints 2
System.out.println(withOutLimit.length); // prints 4
```

Comment: You are not answering the question whether there is any difference between split(regex) and split(regex, limit=0)

Comment: @nhahtdh: Sorry I answered the question now.